# Getting test coverage of GraphQL resolve function

Tags: graphql, mocha.js, integration-testing, graphql-js, supertest

I'm using `mocha` `chai` and `supertest` to test a new graphql endpoint set up on our Node/Express server.

I have all the tests running and passing accordingly but when I run the following script:

```
    "test-coverage": "nyc mocha tests/ --recursive",
```

it is not counting the tests for `users` resolve function in the code coverage.

My graphql query endpoint looks as shown below:

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: () => ({
        users: {
            type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
            args: {
                searchByName: { type: GraphQLString },
                queryNearbyUsers: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
                skip: { type: GraphQLInt },
                limit: { type: GraphQLInt }
            },
            async resolve(parent, args, req) {
                const { searchByName, queryNearbyUsers, skip = 0, limit = 20 } = args
                
                // No search criteria was specified so just return an error
                if(!searchByName && !queryNearbyUsers) 
                    throw new Error('NO_SEARCH_CRITERIA_SPECIFIED')

                ...
            }
        },
    ...
})
```

An example of one of my tests:

```
    it('should throw an error (NO_SEARCH_CRITERIA_SPECIFIED) when no params supplied', function(done) {
        request.post('spikeql')
        .set({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`})
        .send({ query: '{ users { _id firstName lastName displayName rpr distanceAway avatar { styles { thumb_square }}}}'})
        .expect(200) // TODO: Setup GraphQL to match approproate HTTP res codes
        .end((err, res) => {
            if(err) return done(err)
            let errors = res.body.errors
            expect(errors).to.be.an('array')

            // Check to make sure error was sent properly
            expect(errors[0]).to.have.property('message', 'NO_SEARCH_CRITERIA_SPECIFIED')
            expect(errors[0].message).to.be.a('string')
            done()
        })
    })
```

I perform 3 other tests with different inputs for the `GET_USERS` query.  All of them pass.  It just doesn't get tracked in coverage report.

New to graphql and unit/integration testing so any help is appreciated.  Can supply additional info if needed.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete resolve function code you want to test? How did you use `RootQuery`. Do you use the `express` web framework or `http` module?

Comment: @slideshowp2 `express` and my graphql endpoint on the server is shown above.
I'll also an example of the test code I wrote that doesn't get tracked at all.

Comment: @slideshowp2 added example test coverage